# Python 64 bits tem vantagem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, desempenho, memória, 64-bits

Qual a vantagem de usar o Python 64 bits em relação ao de 32 bits? Seria o desempenho?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode até dar algum ganho em alguns pontos quando usa o 64 bits, mas pode ser pior em outros. O maior motivo para usar a versão 64 bits é poder acessar memória superior a 4GB.

Os bits neste contexto são de endereçamento, então 2 elevado a 32 dá pouco mais de 4 bilhões de endereços de memória possíveis, portanto esse é o limite. 64 bits permite 16 quintilhões que é absurdamente mais do que qualquer computador terá mesmo no próximo século.

Quando o usa consome mais memória também, então não é vantajoso se não precisa muito. E não deve usar em máquina que não tem mais que 4GB de memória, e não pode instalar em sistema operacional ou arquitetura que não seja 64 bits, e não vale muito a pena se não precisar usar muita memória mesmo que esteja disponível.

Pode complicar algumas coisas como a coleta de lixo, algumas operações podem custar mais para fazer, então só vale se for muito importante.

Mas também é verdade que pode ficar disponível algumas instruções de processador que alguns cálculos podem ser feitos mais rapidamente, desde que tenha sido compilado pensando nisso. Não é que seu código será mais rápido, mas o código das bibliotecas e *runtime* podem rodar um pouco mais rápido.

Não muda em outros aspectos e vale para qualquer software, não é algo específico de Python.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado Maniero pela explicação! É como eu imaginei a arquitetura de 64bits só tem relevância em caso de demanda de muita memória RAM!

Comment: @PinheiroNeto agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.